# Maltese language in iOS devices

Tags: ios, keyboard, language

I would like to type in Maltese (using Maltese letters) from my iPad and iPhone. Unfortunately, the Maltese langauge is not listed with the default European languages on iOS devices. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure whether the extra characters required for Maltese (ċġħż) might all be available in the layout for another language or not.  It would be kind of tedious to check.  But there are a couple apps, Unicode Map and UniKey, which let you create a sort of custom keyboard layout using any Unicode characters which can be used for copy/paste, etc.

You should also search the app store on Maltese to see if anyone has created a keyboard for that for copy/paste or email, etc.  I see there is an app called 1Hand Mail/SMS Maltese Keyboard that may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I have just released an app that gives you a Maltese Keyboard on iOS devices :)

https://itunes.apple.com/mt/app/maltese-keyboard/id940508915?mt=8

Comment: Thank you for being honest in mentioning it's your App. You may include some more information about this keyboard rather than just providing the link. :)

Comment: It's basically an iOS8 keyboard that provides the same QWERTY layout that everyone is used to but with added Maltese characters.

N.B. there is an option to allow full access. This is only there to enable keyboard click sounds and may be left disabled if this feature is not required.

Answer (score 0):

From a lobbying standpoint, http://www.apple.com/feedback is a nice place to get iOS users that would like have support added for a new localization.

You could suggest which settings are closest and enumerate the changes needed. Perhaps if a few people suggested what was needed, official support might be added in an update. The other answer has more practical suggestions and perhaps a jailbreak or other app might help at least to write things you could copy / paste into non Maltese aware apps that use the system keyboard.